# Lossless Files on Shutter Encoder

Tags: windows-11, video-conversion

I saw that you can make animated WEBP and J2K files on Shutter Encoder. But are they lossless? I want to convert a video into these formats, but I don't know if they will be lossless using Shutter Encoder.

Answer (score 0):

This was asked in the Redit post
[Hi Paul, can we do “lossless” h265 encodes?](https://www.reddit.com/r/shutterencoder/comments/13xqvbh/hi_paul_can_we_do_lossless_h265_encodes/)

The answer by the developer paulpacifico was:

> I do not implemented the lossless compression because the file size
> is most of the time bigger than the source file (even compared to
> ProRes 422...).
>
> - Using a 'CQ' value of '1' is a good compromise (even if it's not lossless) the quality is indistinguishable.
> - You can also use the 'FFV1' function which is made for that and lossless, it's H.264 based but can only be decoded by FFmpeg (backend
>   tool of SE and many other open source encoders).
> - If you really need the lossless compression from H.265, let me know. It's not hard to implement but I'm not sure it's usefull.

It seems like this option is not implemented, but you may ask this of
the developer.